# Sharding in MongoDB using C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, sharding

I try to experiment with sharding and make a sample configuration: the simplest one for two shards. Here is the code from bat files:

```
cd c:\mongodb-win32-x86_64-1.8.3-rc1\bin 
call mongod --shardsvr --dbpath /data/db/Shard--port 10000 
cd c:\mongodb-win32-x86_64-1.8.3-rc1\bin 
call mongod --shardsvr --dbpath /data/db/Shard2 --port 10001 
cd c:\mongodb-win32-x86_64-1.8.3-rc1\bin 
mongod --configsvr --dbpath /data/db/config --port 20000 
cd c:\mongodb-win32-x86_64-1.8.3-rc1\bin 
mongos --configdb 192.168.0.23:20000 
cd c:\mongodb-win32-x86_64-1.8.3-rc1\bin 
mongo 
use admin 
db.runCommand( { addshard : "192.168.0.23:10000" } ) 
db.runCommand( { addshard : "192.168.0.23:10001" } ) 
db.runCommand( { enablesharding : "Shard" } ) 
db.runCommand( { shardcollection : "Shard.Customers", key : 
{LocalIdentifier : 1} } )
```

When I try executing a simple inserting code to this DB, it executes 
but both shards are empty. Here is the inserting code:

```
public void SaveBatch(IEnumerable<object> entities) 
{ 
    MongoCollection.InsertBatch(typeof(object), entities, SafeMode.True); 
}
```

Also this is the code executing on connection:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString; 
mongoServer = mongoServer.Create(connectionString); 
mongoDatabase = mongoServer.GetDatabase("Shard"); 
mongoCollection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<Customer>("Customers"); 
mongoCollection.EnsureIndex( 
    IndexKeys.Ascending(new[] {"CampaignId", "LocalIdentifier", "ProjectIdentifier", "FirstName", "LastName"}));
```

So I did not manage to make the shards work. Can you tell me what I am 
wrong at: configuring, connecting or inserting? And what is the right 
way to do it?

Comment: Case closed, there was a mistake in calling code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution posted in the question works fine

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you're sharding Shards.Customers, but inserting into Riverdale.Customers. Am I missing something?

Comment: No you are right but I just didn't rename the DB for the sample, so this is not the real problem

Comment: Is your call to SaveBatch wrapped in a using(mongoDatabase.RequestStart())?

Comment: Christian, thank you, the issue is solved, I just do not know how to mark it as solved. There was another problem with my other piece of code

Comment: Out of interest: What was the problem?

Comment: The chunks of data sent were empty because of some bad partitioning functionality in the code which is not even present in the question